# Unable to properly show content in all devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I'm making a car research/ranking website using React. Coming to the issue, I have 3 cards, with content on it once you hover over it.

It works perfectly well in desktops, but it doesn't properly show content in smaller devices: it overflows to the other section.

To fix this, I have added a media query to it, but it doesn't work either.

Please check my code:

```
.sec2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)),
    url(https://static.feber.se/article_images/48/81/62/488162_1920.jpg)
      no-repeat top center;
}



.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: fill;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.card:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.card .info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card .info h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.card .info p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.card .info button {
  padding: 0.6rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.card .info button:hover {
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .card {
    height: 270px;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .card .info h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .card .info p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .card .info button {
    padding: 0.4rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .card {
    height: 15%;
    padding: 0.3rem;
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .card .info h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .card .info p {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .card .info button {
    padding: 0.3rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

And

```
<div>
          <header className="sec2" id="section2">
            <h1>
              What is in this website?
            </h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://cdn.jdpower.com/JDPA_2022%20Genesis%20G70%20Red%20Front%20Quarter%20View.jpg" />
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>Car Rankings</h1>
                  <p>
                    It contains cars ranked based on body type, done after
                    comprehensive research.
                  </p>
                  <button>Go</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://i0.wp.com/autonxt.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/autocontentexp.com2018-Lincoln-Navigator5-5b1aebecc618f268352b037fb2253a291d670994-1.jpg?resize=2500%2C1500&ssl=1" />
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>Car Reviews</h1>
                  <p>Contains reviews of selective cars written by us.</p>
                  <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://static0.hotcarsimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/AWD-e1600115646672.jpg" />
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>Used Cars/h1>
                  <p> We rank used cars so that you will only get the best out of it.

                   
                  </p>
                  <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </header>
</div>
```

Image in computer: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qokcg.jpg), and
Image in smaller devices: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gBTl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first add the `margin: auto` in `.wrapper` class and some `margin: 5px;` to `.card` class because this make content in the center and looks good.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.card {
  /* your code */
  margin: 5px;
}
```

- Now, add just update `margin: 15px;` of all `.card` instead of `margin-bottom`

Here is the full code, https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-gwen-4i47v5?file=/src/Home.jsx

Comment: Thanks for responding. I guess you've misunderstood my problem. The thing is, the card is working properly in computers, but it is overflowing to the next section in smaller devices. What you suggested did not solve my problem.

Comment: sorry for that but you should have included that code in question, without knowing the other section it is not possible to solve the issue. If your code is on `GitHub` then share the link.

Comment: okay, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bash-59y4bt?file=/src/index.js

Comment: all section overflow content fixed check out : https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-gwen-4i47v5?file=/src/Home.jsx

Comment: thanks so much!!! You can add the link in your answer so that I can mark as accepted answer